# Do we have any (Eclipse ) opensource IDE support for Karaf +Camel Development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, apache-camel, apache-karaf

We are using

Build: Gradle

OSGI: Karaf + felix

Frameworks: Camel, Bleuprint

We are facing lot of issues with Camel+Blueprint+Karaf Development.

1. Can any body suggest how to run from eclipse ?
2. Do we have any plugins for Eclipse?
3. how to run application from Eclipse (not using remote debugging from karaf console) ?
4. Any work going on Eclipse + karaf Plugins ?

Comment: Not sure what your problems are but you can run it perfectly fine with Intellij Community Edition.

Comment: Analyze how you do it from the command line, and create a launcher that does the same.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [Fuse Tooling](https://tools.jboss.org/features/apachecamel.html) which is providing graphical Tooling for Camel. It is based on Eclipse. You can download it from this [download page](https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/download/)

I don't understand what you mean by "run an application without remote debugging", usually it is launched without remote debugging.

regards,